# Disclose industry salary as COI at academic conference?

Tags: conference, industry, conflict-of-interest

I'm a recent transfer from academic to industry research. I am submitting to a conference in my new company's field, and I am disclosing COI -- organization (my company), relationship ("employment"), relationship ("salary from employment"). Then they want "dollar amount". Regrettably they are not more specific than that. Is it customary to put:

- one year's base salary?
- total income from my employer for one year?
- all they have ever paid me?
- something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that the form was intended for academic researchers who are funded in the form of industry grants. In that case, the size of the grant would be the right number. In your case, I would leave it open -- nobody needs to know your salary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are forced to enter a number, then I'd suggest entering the largest number that could possibly represent the conflict of interest.

If you can enter text, I would suggest "My company sells X, which is useful for Y."  This makes clear what the conflict actually is.

Do not leave it blank, in case a pedantic person considers that dishonest.  There is no need to disclose your salary.

Comment: What is "the largest number that could possibly represent the conflict of interest", if it's not your salary?

Comment: @NateEldredge Total compensation is almost always greater than salary.  The asker's financial situation could be complex.  Benefits? Bonus?  Stock options?  Employer paying for travel?  Any of those things could contribute to conflict of interest.  I'd just round up to the nearest order of magnitude.